# Copy all text from URL and store in an object

Tags: javascript, json, url, text, readfile

I need to copy the text from the URL which a JSON file. I need simple javascript, I cannot use AJAX calls because I have same origin policy error.

The link is as follows:
http://webapp.armadealo.com/home.json?within=50&lng=-71.071123&lat=42.3526751

I need all the content in the above link to be stored in a variable, lets say `var allText`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot use AJAX calls because I have same origin policy error.

Then you cannot get the text directly, full stop, via client-side JavaScript (unless the server that's hosted on supports [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) and allows requests from your origin *and* you're using a CORS-enabled browser). You might be able to do something like [using YQL as a proxy](http://ajaxian.com/archives/using-yql-as-a-proxy-for-cross-domain-ajax), but barring that, you'll need your own server-side proxy.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
```

Comment: He needs to get the content from the URL, not the URL itself.